# Reset SMC without Option and Control key

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, power-management

I need to reset SMC on my Macbook Pro 15 2018 to try fix power problems (macbook goes to sleep even though its disabled with `sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1`).

The problem is, I spilled some water on my macbook and the only two keys not working are Control and Option.

Is there any other way to reset SMC?

Comment: Have you tried using an external **USB Keyboard**? On the external keyboard press the **⌃⌥** and on the **MacBook Pro** press **⇧-Power Button**  Assuming you are following the directions for **Reset the SMC on computers that have the T2 chip**  at: [How to reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201295)

Comment: @user3439894 The SMC reset keychord is hardwired between the built-in keyboard and the T2 through a four-pin `AND` gate. It doesn’t work with external keyboards, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the SMC user reset mechanism is hardwired to the built-in keyboard, the unavailability of your left control and left option keys makes that mechanism **inaccessible**. (An external keyboard *will not work*.)

The SMC runs on battery power so the only other way to reset it is by **disconnecting or fully draining your battery**. You can try this if you feel comfortable with the hardware.

---

I am more inclined to suspect, however, that **resetting the SMC will not ultimately resolve your issue**. The advice to "reset your SMC" is ***very excessively*** given here at Ask Different, and in most situations it is in fact not called for in order to root-cause and resolve a given issue. There are very specific reasons to reset the SMC and most problems do not require it.

Now, the SMC is heavily involved in power management and sleep sequencing, so there may indeed be a reason for trying a reset in your case. However, I would suggest that you first create a separate question and ask for help on debugging the actual symptom you are experiencing (system sleeping despite your attempt to disable it via `pmset disablesleep=1`).

If you do so, you may find helpful suggestions, such as:

- Did you also add `sleep=0` to your `pmset` arguments?
- What does `pmset -g log` show you around the timestamp of the unexpected sleep?